# Thawing Turkey with cold and refrigerator methods

Tags: food-safety, refrigerator, water, turkey, thawing

After I have started with cold water method for partial thawing, when I switch back to refrigerator should ai remove Turkey from original wrapper, pat dry, and place in another bag to complete the defrosting in the refrigerator?